# Meteor accessing helpers from other helpers

Tags: templates, meteor, helper

I'm new to Meteor and its API / philosophy, so I might be thinking about this the wrong way.

I want to display some new friend requests on a page or a message if there aren't any. Here's some code:

```
// addfriend.js
Template.friendRequests.helpers({
  friendRequests: function () {
    return [
      { username: 'alice' },
      { username: 'carl' },
      { username: 'eve' },
    ];
  },

  hasFriendRequests: function () {
    var template = Template.instance();
    return template.helpers.friendRequests.length > 0;
    }
});

// addfriend.html
<template name="friendRequests">
  <h2>Friend requests</h2>
  {{#if hasFriendRequests}}
    <p>Someone's popular today!</p>
    <ul>
    {{#each friendRequests}}
      <li>{{username}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{else}}
    <p>Sorry, nobody likes you right now.</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

My problem is that `friendRequests` will ultimately be a MongoDB query and I want `hasFriendRequests` to *not* repeat that query. I just want it to act on the `friendRequests` helper. But the code I have above does not work for that.

More generally, I'm interested in being able to apply any function `f` to an expensive helper so that I don't have to recompute it. So if you can illuminate me, that'd be awesome!

One way I can think of doing this is by putting the data in `Session` and working from it there. Is this how this should be done?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!
Alin

**Edit:** I realize `friendRequests.length` works here actually, but I'm still interested in how to do this in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this will eventually be a mongodb query, you will most likely set up this friend request list as a published collection. In meteor this means that this collection is being copied over the wire on the initial page load, and only being sent once.

Once on the client, both your friend requests helper and your hasFriendRequests will use this same client side data. The data is actually copied into a client side mini mongodb database that just has the information subscribed to.

So the short answer is, there will only be one DB query for this, because meteor will do all the magic for you.

The key will be in setting up your publication and subscription. So assuming you only play blush and subscribe to it once. You are all set.

Comment: Yes, I can imagine these optimizations will save me a query. But I don't want to rely on this mini MongoDB whose caching protocol I don't understand. Would registering a helper with `registerHelper(getLength, ...)` and calling it in the HTML template with `{{# if getLength friendRequests}}` be the right way of doing this?

Comment: I think the usual way of doing things like this is making multiple queries on Minimongo - usually making several queries on the frontend is not going to be the bottleneck for your app.

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you!